# Fill values of a column based on mean of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame. I'm trying to fill the nans of the Price column based on the average price of the corresponding level in the Section column. What's an efficient and elegant way to do this? My data looks something like this

```
Name   Sex  Section  Price
Joe     M      1       2
Bob     M      1       nan
Nancy   F      2       5
Grace   F      1       6
Jen     F      2       3
Paul    M      2       nan
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use combine `groupby`, `transform`, and `mean`.  Note that I've modified your example because otherwise both Sections have the same mean value.  Starting from

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
    Name Sex  Section  Price
0    Joe   M        1    2.0
1    Bob   M        1    NaN
2  Nancy   F        2    5.0
3  Grace   F        1    6.0
4    Jen   F        2   10.0
5   Paul   M        2    NaN
```

we can use

```
df["Price"] = (df["Price"].fillna(df.groupby("Section")["Price"].transform("mean"))
```

to produce

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
    Name Sex  Section  Price
0    Joe   M        1    2.0
1    Bob   M        1    4.0
2  Nancy   F        2    5.0
3  Grace   F        1    6.0
4    Jen   F        2   10.0
5   Paul   M        2    7.5
```

---

This works because we can compute the mean by Section:

```
In [29]: df.groupby("Section")["Price"].mean()
Out[29]: 
Section
1    4.0
2    7.5
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

and broadcast this back up to a full Series we can pass to fillna() using `transform`:

```
In [30]: df.groupby("Section")["Price"].transform("mean")
Out[30]: 
0    4.0
1    4.0
2    7.5
3    4.0
4    7.5
5    7.5
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

## `pandas` surgical but slower

### Refer to @DSM's answer for a quicker `pandas` solution

This is a more surgical approach that may provide some perspective, possibly usefull

- use `groupyby`

  - calculate our `mean` for each `Section`

    ```
    means = df.groupby('Section').Price.mean()
    ```
- identify nulls

  - use `isnull` to use for boolean slicing

    ```
    nulls = df.Price.isnull()
    ```
- use `map`

  - slice the `Section` column to limit to just those rows with null `Price`

    ```
    fills = df.Section[nulls].map(means)
    ```
- use `loc`

  - fill in the spots in `df` only where nulls are

    ```
    df.loc[nulls, 'Price'] = fills
    ```

---

#### All together

```
means = df.groupby('Section').Price.mean()
nulls = df.Price.isnull()
fills = df.Section[nulls].map(means)
df.loc[nulls, 'Price'] = fills

print(df)

    Name Sex  Section  Price
0    Joe   M        1    2.0
1    Bob   M        1    4.0
2  Nancy   F        2    5.0
3  Grace   F        1    6.0
4    Jen   F        2   10.0
5   Paul   M        2    7.5
```

Comment: Nice post and easy to understand +1

Answer (score 0):

by "corresponding level" i am assuming you mean with equal section value.

if so, you can solve this by

```
for section_value in sorted(set(df.Section)):

    df.loc[df['Section']==section_value, 'Price'] = df.loc[df['Section']==section_value, 'Price'].fillna(df.loc[df['Section']==section_value, 'Price'].mean())
```

hope it helps! peace